# How to sum date on the same column with Crystal Reports

Tags: date, crystal-reports, sum

I need help on sum date. My issue is that all entry date are located on the same column, like:

5/10/2013 
5/13/2013 
5/15/2013 
5/16/2013

I need to sum and get total of 6 days.

Comment: You need to be more descriptive and show us wut u hv trdd

Answer (score 0):

You must be more specific on what you want to achieve.

The number of days can be retrieved by comparing the first date with the last one. To do that, you can create and use a formula field with the following code.

```
datediff("d",minimum({TableName.DateColumnName}),maximum({TableName.DateColumnName}))
```

Comment: Hello David 
Work Fine your code, thanks
went I put the code on group I get the same sum...see example
5/10/2013
5/13/2013
5/15/2013
5/16/2013 
total 11 days (this shut be 6 days)

05/10/2013
05/21/2013
total 11 days

Comment: i need to sum group of date ..this is agropu by workorder I need to know how long the work order stay on a group..thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

Work Fine your code, thanks went I put the code on group I get the same sum...see example 

5/10/2013
5/13/2013
5/15/2013
5/16/2013
Im getting  total 11 days (this shut be 6 days) 

05/10/2013
05/21/2013
total 11 days

how I can make this to work on a group?...thanks for you time